# wlan0 and wlan1 are disconnected - Can I change the status of ''disconnected'' to ''connected''

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, wlan

Recently, on my Kali Linux VM, I installed Compat Wireless 2.6 to install a wi-fi driver. With the command `iwconfig`, I can see `wlan0` and `wlan1`. The problem is they are disconnected. I can't see the other networks. When I download `airmon-ng` on my main machine, i.e. Ubuntu, I can see the other networks with `airodump-ng wlan0mon`, but it is not the case on my kali linux VM.

[image]

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d2:67:e4:1a:25:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 1e:03:e6:42:61:79  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

With the command `sudo iwlist scanning`

```
wlan1     No scan results

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

hwsim0    Interface doesn't support scanning.
```

How can I change the status ''disconnected'' to ''connected''? Is it a problem with the VM?

Comment: Connect to a WiFi network? Presumably ypou need their name(s) and credentials to connect...

Comment: Where  with Kali Linux can I connect to a Wi-Fi network?

Comment: To be honest, I can't see the wifi networks.

Comment: What VM are you using? How is network setup in VM?

Comment: I am using VM virtualbox

Comment: So has your usb wifi adapter been passed through?

Comment: Bridge your network adapter from the Virtualbox settings so the the VM can use your physical adapter